# ASP.net - building online basketball manager how to keep game logic running

Tags: c#, asp.net

my question is this, how can i simulate a text base basketball game in a web application.

The game logic class is ready and in use in  my WPF application, however I want to transfer it to a web base application.
But I have no idea how to keep the game thread a live + updating the UI every second.(only text update are required).

Any ideas ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try to start the main thread in the application_start method of your global.asax file.

But to refresh UI, it's the client browser that will request the data to the server every "x" seconds (with a setTimeout).